# Eclipse / CFBuilder - Keeping track of changed files.

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-plugin, coldfusionbuilder

I have just started working with a new Coldfusion  project, well the project is very much existing I'm the new part.

Currently there is one set of source files and one set of live files. There is not version control or anything like that so all IDE's just work on the same set of files. We are working on a solution to this but in the mean time I was wondering if there is a plugin ofr eclipse that just keeps a list of edited files?

I was hoping before I start a task, I "reset" the edited list, do my work, then publish all the files in the edited list and so on. currently I need to keep a list of files I've changed in a notepad document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse now comes with [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) included, so you could "share" your project (as in, put in version control in a Git repo) and you would get precisely the feature you are looking for.

Without any version control, you do have the [Eclipse local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm), but it is a file-by-file information only.

Comment: Adding to version control would be perfect, but due to circumstances beyond my control... I can't, anything I do can only be local and not affect the files in anyway as the project source is on a shared file/dev server

Comment: @tyrongower: but Git is purely *local*: no client server involved.